# Kendo UI Editor - Encoded true doesn't work property

Tags: kendo-ui, editor

I want to get the letters as they are without modification but Kendo still encoded characters like "áéíóú" to `"&aacute;&eacute;&iacute;&oacute;&uacute;"`

```
KendoRTE = $(".myRte").kendoEditor({  
    encoded: true,
    paste: function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    },
    change: function() {
        console.log(this.value());
    }
}).data('kendoEditor');
```

- [Kendo UI Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/editor#configuration-encoded)
- [Example code of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/joaquinrivero/E32m7/2/)

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this *trick*:

```
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(this.value()).text();
console.log(decoded);
```

Your example modified in here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/E32m7/3/

Comment: Works, but I'm using in a form, so I need to modify a parser to send the form fileds, and before this feature was automatic, thanks

Comment: Then, why not doing it in the server?